# How can I compare the time-complexity O(n^2) with O(N+log(M))?

Tags: time-complexity

My Lua function:

```
for y=userPosY+radius,userPosY-radius,-1 do 
  for x=userPosX-radius,userPosX+radius,1 do
    local oneNeighborFound = redis.call('lrange', userPosZone .. x .. y, '0', '0')
    if next(oneNeighborFound) ~= nil then
      table.insert(neighborsFoundInPosition, userPosZone .. x .. y)
      neighborsFoundInPositionCount = neighborsFoundInPositionCount + 1
    end
  end   
end
```

Which leads to this formula: (2n+1)^2
As I understand it correctly, that would be a time complexity of O(n^2).

How can I compare this to the time complexity of the GEORADIUS (Redis) with O(N+log(M))? https://redis.io/commands/GEORADIUS

> > Time complexity: O(N+log(M)) where N is the number of elements inside the bounding box of the circular area delimited by center and radius and M is the number of items inside the index.

My time complexity does not have a M. I do not know how many items are in the index (M) because I do not need to know that. My index changes often, almost with every request and can be large.

Which time complexity is when better?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `N` and `M` were *independent* variables, I would treat `O(N + log M)` the same way you treat `O(N3 - 7N2 - 12N + 42)`: the latter becomes `O(N3)` simply because *that's* the term that has most effect on the outcome.

This is especially true as time complexity analysis is not really a case of considering runtime. Runtime has to take into account the lesser terms for specific limitations of `N`. For example, if your algorithm runtime can be expressed as `runtime = N2 + 9999999999N`, and `N` is always in the range `[1, 4]`, it's the *second* term that's more important, not the first.

It's better to think of complexity analysis as what happens as `N` approaches infinity. With the `O(N + log M)` one, think about what happens when you:

- double `N`?
- double `M`?

The first has a much greater impact so I would simply convert the complexity to `O(N)`.

However, you'll hopefully have noticed the use of the word "independent" in my first paragraph. The only sticking point to my suggestion would be if `M` was actually some *function* of `N`, in which case it *may* become the more important term.

Any function that reversed the impact of the `log M` would do this, such as the equality `M = 101010N`.